# Translation question from english to symbolic sentence?

Tags: logic

Universe the real numbers.

1. between any integer and any larger integer there is a real number.

$\forall x \forall y$ $(x \in Z \wedge y \in Z \wedge y>x \rightarrow \exists k (x<k<y)$

1. Every nonzero real number is positive or negative.

$\forall x(x\not=0 \rightarrow x>0 \lor x<0$

3.
All people hate some taxes.

$\forall x \exists y$( if x is a person and y is a tax then x hates y)

Comment: 1 & 2 are correct, but missing closing-brackets. (Intentionally?) 3 is incorrect. It should be "for all $x$, if $x$ is a person, then there exists $y$ such that $y$ is a tax and $x$ hates $y$."

Comment: I see so when you say All people hate taxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix (add) parentheses, and on number $(1)$, you need to say that $k \in \mathbb R$:

$$\forall x\forall y\Big((x \in \mathbb Z \wedge y \in \mathbb Z \wedge y>x )\rightarrow \exists k (k \in \mathbb R \land x< k <y)\Big)$$

Same thing for $(2)$. Here we need to specify $x \in \mathbb R$:

$$\forall x\Big((x\in \mathbb R \land x\not=0) \rightarrow (x>0 \lor x<0)\Big)
$$
For $(3)$, $$\forall x\Big(\text{Person}(x)\rightarrow \exists y(\text{Tax}(y) \land \operatorname{Hates}(x, y))\Big)$$

Comment: I see so you cannot have in the antecedent both x is a person and y is a tax because In english what is being said is " All people hate some taxes" "if someone is a person, then there exists a tax y such that this person hates the tax"

Comment: Exactly, Fernando.

Comment: This translation can be a bit confusing....

Comment: So if you had  "All people hate all taxes" It would be $\forall$ x( x is person $\rightarrow$ $\forall y$ y is a tax x hates y

Comment: It becomes easier to understand, with practice, and it helps if you put down your answers, for a day or so, and then return to them to read back *exactly* what you wrote, and see whether it states the original sentence. You may spot some missing info, or incorrect translations, that way.

Comment: In that case, the universally quantified $y$ can be placed at the start to get $$\forall x \forall y([P(x) \land T(y)]\rightarrow H(x, y) \equiv \forall x (P(x)\rightarrow \forall y (T(y) \rightarrow H(x, y)))$$